# Confused about if this is a Riemann sum.

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

The question in its original form is as follows. $$\text {Find the value of } \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum _{k=0} ^{k=n} \left(\int _{\frac {k}{n}}^{\frac {k+1}{n}} \sqrt {(nx-k)(1-(nx-k))}dx\right) $$ .$$\text {Attempt } $$ After substituting $nx-k=u $ the problem changes to computing $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum _0^n \left(\int\sqrt {(u )(1-u)}du\right)\frac {1}{n}$$ Now I dont know what to do with this sum. Is this a Riemann sum so that the ultimate form is computing $$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1\sqrt {u(1-u)}du\right)du $$.

Comment: what are the integration limits in your second formula?

Comment: Also, what's the summation index in the second displayed equation? Please go ahead and show ALL the details, so we can help discover where you're having troubles.

Comment: Finally, why are you using the same "variable of integration" (namely $u$) in *both* of the integrals in the final displayed equation?

Comment: your integral is $$\frac{\pi}{8n}$$

Comment: @John Huges I dont know whether I should put it as k so I have left it like that.

Comment: @Dr Sonhard Graubner can you tell us how did you get that.

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\int_0^1\sqrt{u(1-u)}\,\mathrm du\right)\frac {1}{n}$$

Now set $$C:=\int_0^1\sqrt{u(1-u)}\,\mathrm du$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\int_0^1\sqrt{u(1-u)}\,\mathrm du\right)\frac {1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n C=C\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n=C$$

Of course it can also be written as

$$\int_0^1 C\,\mathrm dx=C$$